# IDE Light Not Showing HD Access

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

The IDE light on my computer blinks when the CD is accessed but not when there's hard drive activity.  Isn't the light supposed to come on with any activity on the IDE channels?

Comment: Use this...http://www.hddled.com/, small unobtrusive led lights on the desktop, can be drug to any postition.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your HDD is not connected to a secondary PATA/SATA controller?  The drive activity light sometimes (usually?) only works for drives connected to the motherboard's chipset's main controller in the southbridge.